# Google Sheets Pie Chart

Tags: google-sheets

not sure if this is the right place to post this, but here goes.

Say I have the following column of data in google sheets:
[image]

And say that I wanted to continuously add to the column as I go and listen to more artists. How can I have a pie chart which represents which artists I listen to the most, and have it automatically update with each new entry I add the column? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it excel or google sheets? not the same although you have both tagged

Comment: You may want to look here:
[How to group data in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/how-to-group-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste this formula into **G1** cell and create the chart from there:

```
=QUERY(F1:F, "select F,count(F) 
              where F is not null 
              group by F 
              label count(F)''", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to avoid plotting `NaNs`?

Answer (score 0):

In google sheets, this can be solved in three columns:

Column C: your list of artists, input as you said
Column B: =Countif(C:C,A1)
Column A: =UNIQUE(C:C)

The pie chart should check column A for labels, and column B for its series.

You will have to drag down the equation in Column B to be as long or linger than your list. Also, this is case sensitive, but you should be able to deal with that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What your asking for is considered a "Group By" in SQL. Google Sheets has these capabilities. See [here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/) for a full explanation (scroll down to Group By section).

[image: Snippet from the link:]